# Do we have any alternative of finding x-path for selenium after discontinuation for firebug and firepath?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, firebug, firepath

As we all know that firebug and firepath has been discontinued. Does any one have any alternative of finding X-path like firebug and firepath??

Comment: Chrome is always there. press F12 and mouse hover to the element in the HTML DOM, right click and copy as xpath.

Comment: Please see answer and If helpful Please accept and upvote

Comment: What have you googled to find an answer? Also, using some tool to find an XPath locator for you is not a very good practice. It generally ends up with very long, brittle locators. You should spend some time learning CSS selectors and how to create them by hand. They are faster and better supported than XPaths.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **xpath helper** and **Relative XPath Helper** for Chrome and firefox

For firefox you can also use : WebDriver Element Locator

**https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/element-locator-for-webdriv/**